# Is there a purpose to having a constant for null?

Tags: java, null, constants

I recently saw something in some code that made me curious if it was actually having some kind of optimization or performance impact.  It was a line like this in a constants file:

```
public static final Object NULL = null;
```

Then, throughout the code, rather than explicitly using the `null` keyword, it would be referred to with `Constants.NULL`.

I've seen this kind of thing before with something like:

```
public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
```

... and that seemed to make at least a little bit of sense, if it's an attempt to avoid creating lots of duplicate `""` instances.  But does it really make any difference with `null`, since it's not actually any kind of object?  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like totally useless to me.

Comment: If it was `private static final Object NOT_FOUND = null;` or something, then I'd understand. But this...

Comment: There are no duplicate `""` instances - Java maintains a string literal pool.

Comment: @us2012 I thought the idea was "sometimes two string literals match up, but sometimes they don't", hence the never ending questions about `==` vs `.equals()`?

Comment: @Jeff The OP's reason is wrong, it's not that EMPTY_STRING isn't (sort of) useful as a way to be very explicit. Although IMO "" is pretty explicit, it might be slightly easier to reason about EMPTY_STRING since "" is small, and who knows what unicode char might look similar, especially depending on the font.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote.

Comment: I also disagree with the close vote. And the answer is that there is absolutely no purpose to these. EMPTY_STRING is 11 characters longer than the perfectly good ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that defining and using `NULL` in this manner does more than add noise. Perhaps whoever wrote that code came from a C++ background, and preferred the more familiar look of `NULL` over `null`.

The second example is also questionable, since using `""` many times would not result in a separate `String` object created for every use. To quote the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class `String`. This is because string literals - or, **more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.**

Comment: Because this is wrong, there is a use case - see talkol's answer.

Comment: @djechlin if you read the info and examplens in the link, there's nothing related with the code posted by OP.

Comment: @DaveNewton - agreed I got confused here - dv's removed.

Answer (score 5):

Neither makes any sense.  Using `""` in multiple places in your code does not create multiple instances of a String object.  Unless you explicitly call `new String("");` the JVM just creates a pool of Strings and references the one instance of each particular String.

Answer (score -1):

There is a purpose to use the Object.NULL.

Suppose that you have a bunch of code that validates if your object is null or not. So as part of a new feature, you need to use default values in some cases of null object.

With the simple if obj != null you can't track down the places where you object is validates against nullity. But if you use obj != Object.NULL then you can use your IDE/editor to help you to find those usages.

Comment: when you define `static final Object NULL = new Object()` you not only can find references but also can discern between 'is present and null' and 'is not present' which may be useful in validations, maps etc

Answer (score -2):

Does not make any difference in memory occupied due to the string pool concept in java and also it makes the code look more dirty when using NULL constant instead of null or EMPTY_STRING instead of "".

Both of them are self explanatory so there should be no need to create a naming constant for them.